# SyntaxError for cv2.imshow

Tags: python, opencv

I want to use cv2.imshow in a while loop. this loop will break with an if condition.  When I use cv2.imshow out of the loop it works properly but when I add it inside the loop, python return a syntax error massage: invalid syntax.
can you help with some solution?

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

faceDetect=cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
cam=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
rec=cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
rec.read('recognizer/trainingData.yml')
id=0
while(True):
    ret,img=cam.read()
    gray=cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces=faceDetect.detectMultiScale(gray,1.3,5)
    for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),2)
        id,conf=rec.predict(gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
        cv2.cv.putText(cv2.cv.fromarray(img),str(id))
    cv2.imshow("preview",img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1)== ord('q'):
        break
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

error massage

```
    cv2.imshow("preview",img)
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your SyntaxError.  There might be an invisible control character on that line, that didn't survive pasting the code here - if your editor has a "show invisibles" feature, give it a try.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks, for the comment, actually i couldn't find the reason "Why" but when i write all the code again it solved.